# Maximum stay in the US under a B1/B2 visa in a 365 day period

Tags: customs-and-immigration, b1-b2-visas, nexus

I am an Indian citizen and have a B1/B2 visitor visa (and a NEXUS card) for the US. I currently reside in Toronto, where I work, whereas my wife resides in Berkeley, where she works. Due to our job locations, my wife and I do not live in the same country. Nevertheless, we make efforts to visit each other as frequently as possible.

Recently, I became aware of a potential regulation pertaining to the B1/B2 visa category, which states that an immigration officer has the authority to deny entry to the US if an individual has spent more than 180 days (accumulated over multiple visits) within a rolling period of 365 days. I am concerned about how this regulation might impact my ability to visit my wife, and I would greatly appreciate any clarification on this matter.

Answer (score 15):

There is no such regulation.  But there are plenty of other reasons for which they can deny admission.  if you're spending more than half of your time in the US, you might find yourself having trouble with US immigration officers for some of these other reasons.  Most likely they'd suspect that you're working remotely for your Canadian employer while you're in the US, which is not allowed in B-1 or B-2 status.  If they suspect that, they won't let you in.

You should also be careful about tax.  If you spend 183 or more days in the US in any calendar year, you will become a US tax resident and be liable to report (and figure your US income tax on) your entire worldwide income.

Comment: Actually US tax residence is (mostly) determined by the ["Substantial Presence Test"](https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/substantial-presence-test) which can be satisfied by less than 183 days in each of 2 or 3 consecutive years.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 that's correct.  The 183-day threshold arises from the "closer connection" exception to the substantial presence test, which OP would satisfy given the residence permit and employer in Canada.  See https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/closer-connection-exception-to-the-substantial-presence-test

Comment: Thanks a lot for such useful advice! Yesterday, I just had the opportunity to ask an immigration officer in person at the immigration desk. She verified that there is indeed a maximum limit of six months per year for my stay in the United States, even if it is spread across multiple visits. However, despite my thorough search through the pages detailing immigration rules, I have been unable to locate this specific restriction. While acknowledging the possibility of the agent's information being incorrect, I agree that other factors, such as tax considerations, could lead to future denials.

Comment: @PavithranIyer tax considerations won't lead to denials; they'll lead to tax liability.  As to the idea that B-2 visitors are limited to six months in a year, consider that the Code of Federal Regulations specifies a maximum period of admission of one year.  This is obviously not consistent with such a limit.

Comment: @PavithranIyer 8 CFR 214.2(b)(1): "Any B–1 visitor for business or B–2 visitor for pleasure may be admitted for not more than one year and may be granted extensions of temporary stay in increments of not more than six months each...."  Obviously anyone seeking to stay that long is going to be scrutinized to ensure that they are indeed "visitors," and most would not survive that scrutiny, but the possibility is there.  The officer you spoke with was simply poorly trained, as are, unfortunately, many officers.  One once told my sister that having dual nationality is "unconstitutional."

Comment: @PavithranIyer for example, if you are in the US for four months starting on January 1 and then reenter on September 1: (1) you will be readmitted for six months, not two; (2) you will not be in violation of immigration law on December 1st when you exceed six months in the US during the calendar year; (3) if you stay to the 183rd day (the date depends on whether it's a leap year) you _also_ won't be in violation of tax law, but you will be the next year if you fail to file an income tax return.